# Input pattern regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I was looking for a pattern that allows only 6 numbers with hyphen separating in the middle like `123-456`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can use regexp:

e.g.

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" pattern="\d{3}-\d{3}">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: doesn't this also allow strings like ABC123-456ABC? I would suggest to add ^ in the beginning and $ to the end.

Comment: @misanthrop No, it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the following pattern and to add a placeholder to make it clear for the user:

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="123-456" pattern="\d{3}-\d{3}"><input type="submit">
</form>
```

`\d` is a shorthand for `[0-9]`, meaning it must match a single digit.
`{3}` means that you need 3 times the previous rule.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy :)

```
/^\d{3}-\d{3}$/
```

Answer (score -2):

```
\d{3}-\d{3}
```

should work. Basically, we seperate three digits with a hypen. You can try [here](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: this won't work, as it allows for multiple hyphens (e.g. `123-----123`). You need to remove the `+` quantifier.

Comment: sorry, i edited my answer.

Comment: And there´s  no need to escape the hyphen...